# How to prove $ ( p \land q ) \land \big( ( q \land \neg r ) \lor ( p \land r ) \big) $ is logically equivalent to $ \neg ( p \to \neg q ) $.\

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Construct a chain of logical connectives to show that (p ∧ q) ∧ [(q ∧ ¬r) ∨ (p ∧ r)] is
logically equivalent to ¬(p → ¬q).
Do not use truth tables here and give a reason for each line.

I could not get to $ \neg ( p \to \neg q ) $.

Comment: A "chain of logical connectives" sounds like you're supposed to use equational reasoning of some sort, yet you've tagged the question "natural deduction". Which of them is it?

Comment: You need to provide the list of logical equivalences and inference rules you're allowed to use.

Comment: I suspect that one of the inferences that you are allowed to make is that $$(A \vee B) ~~\iff~~ \{~ (\text{not} ~A) ~\implies~ B ~\}.$$  Personally, I don't know how to use this to solve the problem; I simply suspect that it may be helpful.

Comment: Notice that $ \neg ( p \to \neg q ) $ is equivalent to $ p \land q$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear from your question whether you have to give a formal derivation using some set of axioms and rules of inference, or merely a chain of logical equivalences like those I've given below.  Without knowing what system of axioms and rules of inference you're supposed to make use of, it's impossible for anyone to provide you with a formal derivation of the first kind.

Here's the chain of logical equivalences I'm referring to above:
\begin{align}
(p\wedge q)\wedge\big((q\wedge\neg r)\vee(p\wedge r)\big)&\equiv\big(((p\wedge q)\wedge (q\wedge\neg r))\vee((p\wedge q)\wedge(p\wedge r))\big)\\
&\hspace{2em}\text{(distributivity of conjunction}\\
&\hspace{2.5em}\text{over disjunction})\\
&\equiv\big((p\wedge q\wedge q\wedge\neg r)\vee(p\wedge q\wedge p\wedge r)\big)\\
&\hspace{2em}\text{(associativity of conjunction)}\\
&\equiv\big((p\wedge q\wedge\neg r)\vee(p\wedge q\wedge r)\big)\\
&\hspace{2em}\text{(idempotency of conjunction)}\\
&\equiv(p\wedge q)\wedge(r\vee\neg r)\\
&\hspace{2em}\text{(distributivity of conjunction}\\
&\hspace{2.5em}\text{over disjunction})\\
&\equiv p\wedge q\hspace{2.5em}\text{(law of excluded middle)}\\
&\equiv\neg\neg p\wedge\neg\neg q\hspace{2em}\text{(double negation)}\\
&\equiv \neg(\neg p\vee\neg q)\hspace{2em}\text{(De Morgan's law)}\\
&\equiv\neg(p\rightarrow\neg q)\hspace{2em}\text{(definition of implication)}
\end{align}

Comment: It may be worth pointing out in your answer that to prove logical equivalence is to prove A entails B, and B entails A. Your proof is obviously reversible, so job done, but I think it's important to make this point explicit